# Change build output directory when building via terminal

Tags: c, macos, build, terminal, output-directory

Recently, I found a program that is kind of a mix between an IDE and a text editor. It supports the syntax of the language and it does formatting, but it does not build and run the program for you. I am running Mac OS X 10.6.8. I looked up how to build C code using the Terminal application. The format is:

```
gcc [file]
```

Pretty simple. The problem is that I cannot change the directory of where the built file is outputted, nor can I change the name. By default, every file compiled is outputted in the home directory by the name of 'a.out.' How can I specify the output directory and name?

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is going to sound rude, but looking up the docs is your best bet. Start here[http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options]

Comment: It's ok. I'm still learning C and I am used to just pressing Command + S and pressing a green arrow on Eclipse to run my Java projects. I didn't know there were docs for the compiler. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

gcc has a `-o` option to change the output name. You can specify the path there. E.g.:

```
$ ls
program.c
$ gcc program.c -o program
$ ls
program   program.c
$ mkdir bin
$ gcc program.c -o bin/program
$ ls bin
program
$
```

You should probably also want to know about a few other common options:

- `-std=c99`, `-std=gnu99`: Use the c99 standard / with gnu extensions.
- `-Wall`, `-Wextra`, `-pedantic`: Enable extra warnings.
- `-O0 -ggdb`: Compile with debugging symbols. Look up how to use `gdb`.
- `-O2`: Compile with processor-independent optimizations. Not compatible with `-O0`.